# Microsoft Subscription Validation fails in Nginx with 405

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, microsoft, boost

I proxy from Nginx to Beast. I have tried Nginx to Apache, same result. My subscription request (made from Boost C++) must wait for Microsoft to POST a validation request to another endpoint. The endpoint works, using the full string below, called through my Admin program, returning the id as text per instructions. However, when received from Microsoft, Nginx gives me this in the access log.

"POST /outlook_notification?validationToken=Validation%3a+Testing+client+application+reachability+for+subscription+Request-Id%3a+60667ad1-fe20-40e2-8fab-c6eecc269905 HTTP/1.1" 405 166 "-" "-"

This happens even when my notificationUrl is passed to a different running server.
Is it possible to receive this kind of validation post in Nginx as a reverse proxy? Here is my location, very simple.

```
    location /outlook_notification {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3003/outlook_notification;
    }
```

Comment: Are you also proxying all the required headers?

Comment: Higher than the location block, there are no restrictions on headers in the config. I read the headers in Beast. But in this case, nothing is passed upstream.